# Referencing objects in HTML in Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am fetching data from an api server and storing it as a object in TypeScript, I need help referencing that data in HTML as a key and value pair.

TypeScript:

```
if (x.AttributeTemplateId==templateId) {
  x['AttributeTemplateValue'].forEach(function(x){
      console.log('hello');
      if (x.AttributeTemplateId==templateId){
        console.log(templateId);
     (function(y){
        console.log("hello2");
       newName.push(y.CodeSet);
       newValue.push(y.CodeValue);
      //  console.log([newAttributes]);
      })(x);
       }
  })
}
})
newName = this.name;
newValue = this.value;
this.attributes = this.name.reduce((acc, value, i) => (acc[value] = this.value[i], acc), {});
console.log(this.attributes);
}
```

My data is in `this.attributes` and it looks like this

[image]

I want to put key and value in a table like

```
<table>
  <tr> 
    <th> Name </th>
    <th> Value </th>
  </tr>
  <tr key>
    <td value > </td>
  </tr>-->
</table>
```

How would I achieve this in Angular2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**step 1**: Create a custom pipe that stores all the object keys and values in an array and returns them just like this

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: objKeys})
export calss objKeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, arguments: string[]) :any {
    let keys= [];
    for (let k in value){
    keys.push({key: k, value: value[k]});
  }
  return keys;
}
```

**setp 2**: in your component template you do the folowing

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let att of attributes | objKeys"> 
  <th>{{att.key}}</th>
  <th>{{att.value}}</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```